# PyScripter for Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyscripter

How to run PyScripter if you have Python 2.7 installed?
There is a command line parameter for Pyscipter to tell it which pythonXX.dll to use, but I can't get this working.

Answer (score 2):

The front page for the project suggests support for Python 2.6.  From this [ticket](http://code.google.com/p/pyscripter/issues/detail?id=356) in google code, it doesn't seem Python 2.7 is supported yet, or at least there have been no updates to that ticket since Feb 2010.

EDIT:  If it works at all with 2.7, the command line parameters should like:

```
PyScripter --PYTHON27 --PYTHONDLLPATH "C:\My\Python27"
```

You could try leaving out the `--PYTHON27`, but I think PyScritper uses that to decide the Python DLL name ("Python27.dll").

Comment: Yes i know that. 
But there is a command line parameter which tells PyScripter which python version to use(you gave the path to pythonXX.dll).
I tried to use it, but it's not working or I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: It says that cant find the python23.dll, which seems to be the default dll to look for. 
I guess I don't know how to add parameter corectly.

Comment: See my update.  It all depends on whether PyScripter tries to parse the `--PYTHON27` argument or if only accepts some prespecified ones.

Answer (score 1):

Try Pyscripter v2 from pyscripter.googlecode.com

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but searching led me here and the answers contain misinformation with regard to current version of Pyscripter.

***I'm pleased to say 2.5.3 works fine with Python 2.7.4 and doesn't require any command line parameters to do so.***

Answer (score 0):

I have a somewhat old version of PyScripter installed, v2.4.1.0, and it works with the Python 2.7.3 I also have installed.